# Can't connect to WebService after it's been idle until App Pool Recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, timeout

I have a Webservice that is running on IIS and for the most part it works fine. I can call this webservice from a test web app just fine when it is first deployed. If I hit the webservice multiple times close to each other with the same test data it returns results just fine.

If I let the webservice sit idle (I can't figure out how long it takes before it starts to error out, at least an hour) and I try to hit this same webservice I get an internal 500 timeout error returned instantly when trying to hit the same method that was working before. No matter how I call into this webservice (through a windows app, through a web app, through fiddler using a SOAP request) I instantly get this error back. There is no way to get it working again until I recycle the app pool that the Webservice is running on.

Edit: Also if it helps, I am still able to bring the webservice asmx page up on a web browser just fine while this error is happening.

Comment: Gotta be some kind of weirdness with your service. I'd say create a simple Hello World service, compare the two (attributes, constructor calls, etc.), and take out the differences one at a time until you find your culprit.